# Plone 4: Getting Vocabulary values in a loop

Tags: python, plone, vocabulary

I am trying to fetch a Named Vocabulary and loop through its contents. Below is the code I have so far.

```
def get_car_types(self):

    car_types = []

    vtool = getToolByName(self, 'portal_vocabularies')
    cars_vocab = vtool.getVocabularyByName('my.package.car_models')

    for terms in cars_vocab:
        print terms.value + ": " + terms.title
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

It points out that the error is somewhere around this line:

```
for terms in cars_vocab:
```

What could be the problem? How does one fetch a named vocabulary and loop through the values? I have been using [this link](http://garbas.github.com/plone-z3c.form-tutorial/vocabularies.html).

Comment: Can you do a print cars_vocab, print type(cars_vocab) right before the for loop and get back with that additional info?

Comment: @Bogdan This is what I get: 2012-02-28 16:00:33 INFO my.product.browser <IMSVDEXVocabulary at my.package.car_models>

Comment: When you report an error, please include the full traceback, not just the exception. That way we can pinpoint *where* your problem occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out another way to make it work. Below is the code.

```
from Products.ATVocabularyManager import NamedVocabulary

def get_car_types(self):        

        car_types = []        
        car_vocab = NamedVocabulary('my.package.car_models')
        car_terms = car_vocab.getDisplayList(self).items()

        for term in car_terms:
            car_types.append( (term[0], term[1]) )

        return car_types
```

Thanks to all the guys who offered to answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

In your loop "terms" is actually the string corresponding to the dictionary's key.
Try this:

```
for value,term in cars_vocab.items():
        print value + ": " + term.title
```

Here value is the key string and term is a SimpleVocabularyTerm object.

Note: when asking for help about modular systems like Plone it is good to always specify any add-ons involved in the issue..(here notably Products.ATVocabularyManager)

Answer (score -1):

You should be calling `term` instead of `terms` inside the loop. Also if `terms.value` is of type `int` you should surround it with `str()`. Try this:

```
print str(term.value) + ": " + str(term.title)
```

Comment: It is not reaching that line. Read my question above. The error is in the line where the for-loop begins.

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected my question above. But still that has not solved my problem yet. :-(

Comment: How do you conclude that a AttributeError on `startswith` is due to an int being appended to a string?

Comment: @MartijnPieters That was just a sidenote. I started that sentence with "Also...". I thought the AttributeError might come from using terms instead of term (he had that bug in his code earlier, he now has fixed that).